# Error in opencv code for motion detection

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am looking for implementation of human motion tracking, also discussed about in [multiple moving object detection](http://sundararajana.blogspot.ca/2007/05/motion-detection-using-opencv.html) extracted from several video frames using differential analysis and lukas kanade optical method.

I found scientific papers and found that we have to use connected components [filtering connected components](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/267697_filtering-connected-components) for continuous motion tracking, but I do not understand how to go about this process. All I need are the [skeletonization](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~palagyi/skel/skel.html) trajectory and the coordinates of human gait motion.

I am working in Opencv and C++, but the documentation in opencv for object detection won't suffice in my case. I am from medical background and need this is a part of a paediatrician project.

I found this code [motion detection](http://sundararajana.blogspot.ca/2007/05/motion-detection-using-opencv.html) and was trying to execute it (don not know if it detects and tracks motion, yet). However, it returns these errors and I am perplexed for the errors are trivial and other comments mention that they are able to run this code. But I cannot mitigate these erros nor can I understand the reason for them occuring. I am using OpenCv2.3 and following are the errors

1. Cannot open surce file stdafx.h
2. warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
3. error C2086: 'CvSize imgSize' : redefinition
4. error C2065: 'temp' : undeclared identifier
5. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

   - error C2365: 'cvReleaseImage' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
     1>          c:\opencv2.3\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core_c.h(87) : see declaration of 'cvReleaseImage'
6. error C2065: 'difference' : undeclared identifier
7. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8. error C2365: 'cvReleaseImage' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
   1>          c:\opencv2.3\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core_c.h(87) : see declaration of 'cvReleaseImage'
9. error C2065: 'greyImage' : undeclared identifier
10. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
11. error C2365: 'cvReleaseImage' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
12. \opencv2.3\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core_c.h(87) : see declaration of 'cvReleaseImage'
    error C2065: 'movingAverage' : undeclared identifier
    -error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    -error C2365: 'cvReleaseImage' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
    -1>          c:\opencv2.3\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core_c.h(87) : see declaration of 'cvReleaseImage'
    -error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    -error C2365: 'cvDestroyWindow' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
13. c:\opencv2.3\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui_c.h(136) : see declaration of 'cvDestroyWindow'
14. error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [10]' to 'int'
    -1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
    -error C2065: 'input' : undeclared identifier
    -error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
15. error C2365: 'cvReleaseCapture' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
    -1>          c:\opencv2.3\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui_c.h(311) : see declaration of 'cvReleaseCapture'
    -error C2065: 'outputMovie' : undeclared identifier
16. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    -error C2365: 'cvReleaseVideoWriter' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
    -1          c:\opencv2.3\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui_c.h(436) : see declaration of 'cvReleaseVideoWriter'
    -error C2059: syntax error : 'return'
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

**CODE**

```
// MotionDetection.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//


// Contourold.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "iostream"
#include "stdlib.h"

// OpenCV includes.
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"cv.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"cxcore.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"highgui.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

//Create a new window.
cvNamedWindow("My Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

//Create a new movie capture object.
CvCapture *input;

//Assign the movie to capture.
//inputMovie = cvCaptureFromAVI("vinoth.avi");

char *fileName = "E:\\highway.avi";
//char *fileName = "D:\\Profile\\AVI\\cardriving.wmv";
input = cvCaptureFromFile(fileName);
//if (!input)

//cout << "Can't open file" << fileName < ;



//Size of the image.
CvSize imgSize;
IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(input);
CvSize imgSize = cvGetSize(frame);

//Images to use in the program.
IplImage* greyImage = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage* colourImage;
IplImage* movingAverage = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3);
IplImage* difference;
IplImage* temp;
IplImage* motionHistory = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

//Rectangle to use to put around the people.
CvRect bndRect = cvRect(0,0,0,0);

//Points for the edges of the rectangle.
CvPoint pt1, pt2;

//Create a font object.
CvFont font;


//Create video to output to.
char* outFilename = argc==2 ? argv[1] : "E:\\outputMovie.avi";
CvVideoWriter* outputMovie = cvCreateVideoWriter(outFilename,
CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', 'I'), 29.97, cvSize(720, 576));

//Capture the movie frame by frame.
int prevX = 0;
int numPeople = 0;

//Buffer to save the number of people when converting the integer
//to a string.
char wow[65];

//The midpoint X position of the rectangle surrounding the moving objects.
int avgX = 0;

//Indicates whether this is the first time in the loop of frames.
bool first = true;

//Indicates the contour which was closest to the left boundary before the object
//entered the region between the buildings.
int closestToLeft = 0;
//Same as above, but for the right.
int closestToRight = 320;

//Keep processing frames...
for(;;)
{
//Get a frame from the input video.
colourImage = cvQueryFrame(input);

//If there are no more frames, jump out of the for.
if( !colourImage )
{
break;
}

//If this is the first time, initialize the images.
if(first)
{
difference = cvCloneImage(colourImage);
temp = cvCloneImage(colourImage);
cvConvertScale(colourImage, movingAverage, 1.0, 0.0);
first = false;
}
//else, make a running average of the motion.
else
{
cvRunningAvg(colourImage, movingAverage, 0.020, NULL);
}

//Convert the scale of the moving average.
cvConvertScale(movingAverage,temp, 1.0, 0.0);

//Minus the current frame from the moving average.
cvAbsDiff(colourImage,temp,difference);

//Convert the image to grayscale.
cvCvtColor(difference,greyImage,CV_RGB2GRAY);

//Convert the image to black and white.
cvThreshold(greyImage, greyImage, 70, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

//Dilate and erode to get people blobs
cvDilate(greyImage, greyImage, 0, 18);
cvErode(greyImage, greyImage, 0, 10);

//Find the contours of the moving images in the frame.
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* contour = 0;
cvFindContours( greyImage, storage, &contour, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

//Process each moving contour in the current frame...
for( ; contour != 0; contour = contour->h_next )
{
//Get a bounding rectangle around the moving object.
bndRect = cvBoundingRect(contour, 0);

pt1.x = bndRect.x;
pt1.y = bndRect.y;
pt2.x = bndRect.x + bndRect.width;
pt2.y = bndRect.y + bndRect.height;

//Get an average X position of the moving contour.
avgX = (pt1.x + pt2.x) / 2;

//If the contour is within the edges of the building...
if(avgX > 90 && avgX < 250)
{
//If the the previous contour was within 2 of the left boundary...
if(closestToLeft >= 88 && closestToLeft <= 90)
{
//If the current X position is greater than the previous...
if(avgX > prevX)
{
//Increase the number of people.
numPeople++;

//Reset the closest object to the left indicator.
closestToLeft = 0;
}
}
//else if the previous contour was within 2 of the right boundary...
else if(closestToRight >= 250 && closestToRight <= 252)
{
//If the current X position is less than the previous...
if(avgX < prevX)
{
//Increase the number of people.
numPeople++;

//Reset the closest object to the right counter.
closestToRight = 320;
}
}

//Draw the bounding rectangle around the moving object.
cvRectangle(colourImage, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1);
}

//If the current object is closer to the left boundary but still not across
//it, then change the closest to the left counter to this value.
if(avgX > closestToLeft && avgX <= 90)
{
closestToLeft = avgX;
}

//If the current object is closer to the right boundary but still not across
//it, then change the closest to the right counter to this value.
if(avgX < closestToRight && avgX >= 250)
{
closestToRight = avgX;
}

//Save the current X value to use as the previous in the next iteration.
prevX = avgX;
}
//Save the current X value to use as the previous in the next iteration.
prevX = avgX;
}


//Write the number of people counted at the top of the output frame.
cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 2);
cvPutText(colourImage, _itoa(numPeople, wow, 10), cvPoint(60, 200), &font, cvScalar(0, 0, 300));

//Show the frame.
cvShowImage("My Window", colourImage);

//Wait for the user to see it.
cvWaitKey(10);

//Write the frame to the output movie.
cvWriteFrame(outputMovie, colourImage);
}

// Destroy the image, movies, and window.
cvReleaseImage(&temp);
cvReleaseImage(&difference);
cvReleaseImage(&greyImage);
cvReleaseImage(&movingAverage);
cvDestroyWindow("My Window");

cvReleaseCapture(&input);
cvReleaseVideoWriter(&outputMovie);


return 0;

}
```

- Kindly help to resolve the errors and issues.
- How to do motion (human) tracking which returns the coordinates of the trajectories probably by skeletonization method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) I presume you have directly copied the code from the website (correct me if I am wrong..). However since you are using OpenCV 2.3 so most of the APIs are in different modules. The following include you should have are...

```
#include <opencv/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

and the respective libraries.

2.) For filtering connected components you can use [cvblob library](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/). I think the old Blob library provided by OpenCV was build using VC 6 so may be that required `stdafx.h`

3.) Go through the code slowly for some syntax and re-declaration error.

**EDITTED CODE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdlib.h"


#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cvNamedWindow("My Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    CvCapture *input;

    //char *fileName = "E:\\highway.avi";
    input = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

    //input = cvCaptureFromFile(fileName);

    CvSize imgSize;
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(input);
    imgSize = cvGetSize(frame);

    IplImage* greyImage = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    IplImage* colourImage;
    IplImage* movingAverage = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3);
    IplImage* difference;
    IplImage* temp;
    IplImage* motionHistory = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

    CvRect bndRect = cvRect(0,0,0,0);

    CvPoint pt1, pt2;

    CvFont font;


    char* outFilename = argc==2 ? argv[1] : "E:\\outputMovie.avi";
    CvVideoWriter* outputMovie = cvCreateVideoWriter(outFilename,
    CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', 'I'), 29.97, cvSize(720, 576));

    int prevX = 0;
    int numPeople = 0;

    char wow[65];

    int avgX = 0;

    bool first = true;

    int closestToLeft = 0;
    int closestToRight = 320;

    for(;;)
        {
        colourImage = cvQueryFrame(input);

        if( !colourImage )
            {
            break;
            }
        if(first)
            {
            difference = cvCloneImage(colourImage);
            temp = cvCloneImage(colourImage);
            cvConvertScale(colourImage, movingAverage, 1.0, 0.0);
            first = false;
            }
        else

            {
            cvRunningAvg(colourImage, movingAverage, 0.020, NULL);
            }

        cvConvertScale(movingAverage,temp, 1.0, 0.0);

        cvAbsDiff(colourImage,temp,difference);

        cvCvtColor(difference,greyImage,CV_RGB2GRAY);

        cvThreshold(greyImage, greyImage, 70, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        cvDilate(greyImage, greyImage, 0, 18);
        cvErode(greyImage, greyImage, 0, 10);

        CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
        CvSeq* contour = 0;

        cvFindContours( greyImage, storage, &contour, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );


        for( ; contour != 0; contour = contour->h_next )
        {
            bndRect = cvBoundingRect(contour, 0);
            pt1.x = bndRect.x;
            pt1.y = bndRect.y;
            pt2.x = bndRect.x + bndRect.width;
            pt2.y = bndRect.y + bndRect.height;

            avgX = (pt1.x + pt2.x) / 2;

        if(avgX > 90 && avgX < 250)
        {
            if(closestToLeft >= 88 && closestToLeft <= 90)
                {
                if(avgX > prevX)
                    {
                    numPeople++;
                    closestToLeft = 0;
                    }
                }
            else if(closestToRight >= 250 && closestToRight <= 252)
                {
                if(avgX < prevX)
                    {
                    numPeople++;
                    closestToRight = 320;
                    }
                }
            cvRectangle(colourImage, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1);
         }

        if(avgX > closestToLeft && avgX <= 90)
            {
            closestToLeft = avgX;
            }

        if(avgX < closestToRight && avgX >= 250)
            {
            closestToRight = avgX;
            }

        prevX = avgX;
        prevX = avgX;

        }

        cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 2);
        cvPutText(colourImage, _itoa(numPeople, wow, 10), cvPoint(60, 200), &font, cvScalar(0, 0, 300));
        cvShowImage("My Window", colourImage);

        cvWaitKey(10);
        cvWriteFrame(outputMovie, colourImage);

    }


    cvReleaseImage(&temp);
    cvReleaseImage(&difference);
    cvReleaseImage(&greyImage);
    cvReleaseImage(&movingAverage);
    cvDestroyWindow("My Window");

    cvReleaseCapture(&input);
    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&outputMovie);


return 0;

}
```

its compiling correctly atleast...its having some run time error...I dont have a debugger to track it right now...try it...i am also trying it..

Comment: Thank you.It still throws the errors(Cannot open include file: 'opencv/core/core.hpp': No such file or directory) and yes I copied the code with the modification mentioned under the comments.On putting those APIs which you mentioned,it is giving red curved line underneath.Could You kindly debug the code as I could not understand the re declaration errors.I am new to opencv and practicing with simple programs and hence such an advanced code is hard to debug.Shall be obliged.Also,how to go about the skeletonization process and will this code do motion tracking?

Comment: Give me some time to debug the code...The code which you have put up here is the final code write?I mean do I need to copy from that website or this code will suffice?

Comment: This is the final code,you need not copy from the website.Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Thanx, but it is terminating by thrwoing exceptions First-chance exception at 0x7624c41f (KernelBase.dll) in Human.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002ff228..
Unhandled exception at 0x7624c41f (KernelBase.dll) in Human.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002ff228..
First-chance exception at 0x0fe8c428 in Human.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
And so on... Also, what was wrong previously and what do these exceptions mean so as to remove them?

Comment: I believe I have to record and save a video.I found this code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400908/how-to-save-output-video-into-a-file-in-opencv , it compiles however it terminates after the webcam opens once and then in console it says "Assertion failed..this application has requested the run time to terminate it in an unusual way, please contact the application's support team." What to do ?please help

Comment: I am executing this on my laptop which has the laptop's camera(inbuilt).

Comment: Yay..it works,but it does not do the tracking as claimed..I can see the red boundary boxes.Could you guide me through(may be in next question) about motion tracking using this code?

Comment: Another last query, the output file of the video outputMovie.avi is created but it is of zero bytes whcih means nothing is recorded.Is there a key or some time duration for the camera to remain on for something to be recorded?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22774/discussion-between-skm-and-rotating-image)

Answer (score 6):

I can spot about 3-4 bugs so far as I try to compile the code.

1. You do not need `#include "stdafx.h"`.
2. You redeclare `imgSize` at the line you use `cvGetSize(frame)`.
3. The last bracket does not match.
4. You may check the function `_itoa()` as it is not declared in the code.