# Saving video as series of images opencv

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, video-capture, video-processing

This question is in continuation of [error-in-opencv-code-for-motion-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309111/error-in-opencv-code-for-motion-detection). The editted code works without any errors but the output video is not created,it is of zero bytes!What is wrong in this?Also,the bounding box created for motion detection never really captures the motion that is, it does not do what it originally claimed to do.Am I misunderstanding something about the objective of thie code?So, here are my questions:

1. How to rectify the creation and save the video?
2. What needs to be modified to detect motion and track it?
3. How to convert the video to a series of numbered jpg images from each frame and vice-versa.

Comment: I think you can try a differnt code given here                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007150/background-subtraction-mog-with-images

Comment: Thank you for the link.According to my understanding, there is no video capture part in the code.My main concern was that after capturing the video,it needs to be saved so as to frame it.However,it is not getting saved.I can then use the code in the link for framing the saved video.So,could you kindly tell me what is wrong in the code and how to save the video.

Comment: To read a video & save it as a video Here is a link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054907/opencv-videowriter-wont-write-anything-although-cvwritetoavi-does/12059944#12059944.... If u want to save it as set of images i will post the code...

Comment: Thank you for the link. I would really appreciate if you can post the code for saving the video as a set of images and possibly can you append that to the code link provided in my question if it is not cumbursome and time consuming.

Comment: Hi,the code in the link returns error,it does not compile!Also, how can I work with cvCreateVideoWriter for saving video.

Comment: HI, can you tell me the error you are getting. Because i was able to run the code in my system.

Comment: The error is displayed in the console "Error cvCreateVideoWriter" . IF you can kindly have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408600/videowriter-error-unable-to-save-video where I have also posted a code for video saving since it is a continuation of this post.

Comment: Hey, I asked to try the code given in answer, where only opencv c++ library is used. Are you trying to compile the code in question in link2?

Comment: I tried to compile the code given by you as well as in link2. The link(Mat) provided by you opens the webcam but creates no video (2kb) which I tried opening in win media player and vlc but returns an error.So, I tried using the code in link2 with IplImage which returns Error cvCreateVideoWriter and Capture Properties 640.0000 X 480.0000 -0.0000 fps Assertion failed: ../...modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmeg_impl.hpp . Could you tell me what is the differnce between Mat and IplImage and cvCapture and VideoCapture?

Comment: Mat is C++ reference data type to hold the image data, where as IplImage is C reference data type to do the same. functions made for c  style are can't be used for C++ style..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which you can work with to frame a video as a set of images.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include <highgui.h>
#include "cxcore.h" 

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{    
     CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("E:\\Myvideo.avi");
             if(!capture) 
    {
        printf("!!! cvCaptureFromAVI failed (file not found?)\n");
        return -1; 
    }

    int fps = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

    printf("* FPS: %d\n", fps);

    IplImage* frame = NULL;
    int frame_number = 0;
    char key = 0;   

    while (key != 'q') 
    {
        // get frame 
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);       
        if (!frame) 
        {
            printf("!!! cvQueryFrame failed: no frame\n");
            break;
        }       




        // quit when user press 'q'
        key = cvWaitKey(1000 / fps);
    }

    // free resources
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

    return 0;
}
```